# Skybrud social instagram stopped working in website

Tags: c#, instagram, umbraco, instagram-api, umbraco7

My website use Umbraco as the CMS and Skybrud.Social for instagram media feed.

it was working fine until a few days ago.

it seems like instagram changed the way their api work now.

the code i'm using is like this.

```
Skybrud.Social.Umbraco.Instagram.PropertyEditors.OAuth.InstagramOAuthData 
client = s.instagramLogin;
var service = InstagramService.CreateFromAccessToken(client.AccessToken);
Skybrud.Social.Instagram.Responses.InstagramRecentMediaResponse response = 
service.Users.GetRecentMedia();
<div class="row">                                    
    @{
        int number = 0;
        foreach (Skybrud.Social.Instagram.Objects.InstagramMedia mediaig in response.Body.Data)
        {
            if(number>=16)
            {
                break;   
            }
            <div class="col-md-3  col-sms-6 col-xs-12">    
                <div class="row" >
                    <a class="template" href="@mediaig.Link">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 templateIconDiv">
                            <div class="templateIconDivContainer">
                                <img class="templateIcon" src="@mediaig.Images.StandardResolution.Url">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            number++;
        }
    }
</div>
```

is there any way to fix this so it worked again?

Answer (score 0):

What is the (specific) error you are getting?

As mentioned on the Skybrud.Social Instagram plugin page (https://social.skybrud.dk/instagram/) you can't really expect all features of the plugin to work. Why or how it has been working for you until now I don't know, but Instagram closed down loads of API endpoints last year and seem to continue to do so. I've given up on integrating Instagram stuff on any of my websites as Instagram themselves seem to not want us to.

Comment: error given is

Skybrud.Social.Instagram.Exceptions.InstagramException: This endpoint has been retired

Comment: @PhilipHoseaChristianto Yeah. That's Instagram not allowing it, tough luck :-/